# self-hosting windows form(singalr server) and webform client(signalr client) on windows server 2008(Error during negotiation request)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr, windows-server-2008, windows-forms-designer

I write a windows form as a signalr server(SignalR = WebApp.Start(@"http://" + szIP + @":9000");) and a webform client as signalr client. I run both them on my computer(Windows 10). I use iPad mini1 and SAM SUNG Galaxy Tab4 connect to my computer by ip. There is no problem during the connection. I deploy the webform to Windows Server 2008 and run the windows form on Windows Server 2008. I also set the setting of firewall rules for the port 9000(TCP). But the connection bewteen windows form and webform client is not successful. The webform client always dispaly the error as below:

Error:Error during negotiation request

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this problem by adding json2.js and restart windows firewall service.